# comprimir imagen al subir la ruta al la base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, imagen, rutas

ojalá me puedan ayudar, tengo un codigo que guarda las rutas de las imagenes y luego las muestra por pantalla, pero necesito comprimirlas imagenes, no he podido realizarlo, si alguien me ayuda se lo agradeceria un montón

```
    public function uploadImage($Imagen)
{

    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    $ruta = 'imagenes/'.$Imagen['imagen']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($Imagen['imagen']['tmp_name'],$ruta);
    $SQLStatement = $this->DBConexion->prepare("INSERT INTO imagenphp (urlPhoto, cliente) VALUES (:url, '$cliente')");
    $SQLStatement->bindParam(":url",$ruta);
    $SQLStatement->execute();
}


/**********************************
Función visualizar las imagenes 
que estan en la ruta guardada en la 
BD
**********************************/
public function viewImages()
{
    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    $SQLStatement = $this->DBConexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM imagenphp WHERE cliente = '$cliente' ");
    $SQLStatement->execute();

    while($img = $SQLStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    ?>
    
        
        <img src="<?php print($img['urlPhoto']); ?>" width="200" >
    
    <?php 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

espero que lo hayas solucionado y si no es así te dejo este ejemplo donde se sube una imagen y después con una función, podemos bajar el peso.

> Creamos un archivo PHP llamado upload.php

```
<?php

//Incluimos la conexión a la BD
include "./db/conexion.php";

//creamos una funcion que nos ayudara a bajar el peso de la imagen subida
        function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality)
    {

        // Obtenemos la información de la imagen
        $imgInfo = getimagesize($source);
        $mime = $imgInfo['mime'];

        // Creamos una imagen
        switch ($mime) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                break;
            case 'image/png':
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                break;
            default:
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        }

        // Guardamos la imagen
        imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

        // Devolvemos la imagen comprimida
        return $destination;
    }

    //Declaramos la ruta donde se guardara la imagen
    $url = './imagenes';


    //Ahora obtenemos los datos enviados por método POST al oprimir el boton de submit

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        //Verificamos si la imagen se ha cargado

        if (!isset($_FILES["img"]) || $_FILES["img"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Ha ocurrido un error.";
        } else {
            $imagenRuta = basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
            $imagenBD = $url_bd . basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
            $imageUploadPath = $url . $imagenRuta;
            $fileType = pathinfo($imageUploadPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $allowTypes = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');
            if (in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)) {

                // Obtenemos la imagen temoporal
                $imageTemp = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];

                // Comprimos el fichero
                $compressedImage = compressImage($imageTemp, $imageUploadPath, 75);

                //Si la compresión se hizo correctamente ejecuta el query y la imagen se guarda
                //en la ruta antes declara junto con el nombre de la imagen y muestra un alert  
                //de exito y si hay error, muestra un alert de error y redirecciona a la pagina principal

                if ($compressedImage) {
                    $res = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `tabla_imagen` (`img`)
            VALUES ('" . $imagenBD . "')");

                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Imagen añadida con exito");
                window.location.href = "index.php";
            </script>';
                } else {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("La imagen no se pudo añadir);
                        window.location.href = "index.php";
            </script>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

> Y asi quedaria en el HTML

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Selecciona una imagen:</label>
<input type="file" name="img">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subir">
```

> Si no quieres crear otro tra vista de php, lo puedes hacer en el mismo archivo así:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
<label>Selecciona una imagen:</label>
<input type="file" name="img">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subir">
```

Espero te haya servido.